# How to display instances of a field (field collection) in tabs?

Tags: entities, routes

I have a content type with a field which has a number of instances (actually, it's a Field Collection with a vimeo embed and a text field). I would like to have each instance of the field to be shown as a tab? Field Group seems like a natural candidate for this role, but from what i understand it enables me only to build tabs for particular fields, not fields instances.

The way I'd dream this functionality to be is:
1) I add another field to my field collection named, say, "Tab title"
2) In "manage display" of the node I set the display of the field to be of "tabbed instance" type.
3) In settings of this display I set the title of the tab to be the new field introduced in 1) by Token.
Of course, any other way of acieving the goal would be also most welcome.
Is there a simple way to obtain such a functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone up there likes you...

[Field Collection Tab formatter](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_tabs)

> Field collection tabs provides a field formatter that allows you to output a multi value field collection field as a tabset, with one tab per field collection item.
>
> **Features**
>
> You can optionally choose a field from the field collection item to be used as the tab title.

It's uncannily close to what you're asking for. Your question might as well have been the user story that inspired that module :)

Comment: That's close. From what I understand, though, it enables me to give peculiar _fields_ to tabs. What i do want, though, is to have _the whole field collction_ in tabs. The collection is video+text. The user can put any number of them in the node, and I want to display all those in tabs.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what it does - _"one tab per field collection item"_. The "field collection item" refers to each individual collection of fields, not the individual fields themselves

Comment: Wow, I'm afraid it'll take me a while to find a module that matches so closely a request I have. I still have some trouble with the tabs names (they do not show up), but I hope I will make it. :-)

Comment: I just had a problem with the names not shopwing up, as I assumed (wrongly) that the field from which the tab name is taken should be excluded from display in the field group. **It should be left to display normally**, or it won't show up in the tab. It won't show in the content (which is what I'd expect). 

@Clive a big thank you for helping me - I actually found the module before, but misunderstood its purpose, and without your clarification I might have been still scratching my head.