# Field collection tabs on node edit form

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a field collection field with 5 text and image fields per field collection item. On a node with lots of field collections, this makes it very difficult to navigate the node edit form.

I am looking for a module to put the field collections into tabs. One tab per field collection. Clicking "add another" would add a new tab with empty fields to the node edit field collection field.

Please note, I have seen [Field Collection Tabs Formatter](http://Field%20Collection%20Tab%20formatter) but this only formats the display, not the node edit form. I have also seen [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88410/how-to-display-instances-of-a-field-field-collection-in-tabs), but same thing, its only for the manage display.

I would be happy to use multifield instead of field collection if there was a solution.

**Note:**
Out of interest, I tried placing the field collection field in a horizontal tabs group using Fieldgroup. Then I tried putting a horiztonal tab around the fields inside the field collection, but this didnt work.

Comment: Have you looked into field_group? (https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) We use it all the time to organise edit panes. Doesn't do exactly what you describe but certainly makes things more manageable.

Comment: Hi Alfred, Yes i can put 4 out 5 fields into a fieldset using field group, but it still restricts the actual fieldcollection items into the draggable rows, and with the fieldsets expanding and collapsing with ckeditor inside, my client is complaining that its too confusing.

Comment: I see what you mean. Haven't come across anything that quite fits with your requirement. In that situation I'd probably roll my own.

Comment: OK no problem. Her budget definitely doesnt warrant that! I would be interested in it in the future though if anyone finds anything